# Nested TreeView in C#.Net

Tags: c#-4.0

I am working in TreeView Concept in C#.Net. My Scenario is like this..I wil have a ROOT NAME. If i expand that, i will have TWO Names. If i expand a Name, I will have TWO SUB NAMES inside that.

```
 foreach (DataRow masterRow in ds.Tables[0].Rows)
            {
                TreeNode masterNode = new TreeNode((string)masterRow["NAME"], Convert.ToString(masterRow["PARENT_ID"]));
                TreeView1.Nodes.Add(masterNode);

                foreach (DataRow childRow in masterRow.GetChildRows("Children"))
                {
                    TreeNode childNode = new TreeNode((string)childRow["NAME"], Convert.ToString(childRow["PARENT_ID"]));
                    masterNode.ChildNodes.Add(childNode);
                    childNode.Value = Convert.ToString(childRow["PARENT_ID"]);

                    foreach (DataRow masterRow1 in ds1.Tables[0].Rows)
                    {
                        TreeNode masterNode1 = new TreeNode((string)masterRow1["NAME"], Convert.ToString(masterRow1["PARENT_ID"]));
                        TreeView1.Nodes.Add(masterNode1);
                        {
                            foreach (DataRow childRow2 in masterRow1.GetChildRows("Children1"))
                            {
                                TreeNode childNode2 = new TreeNode((string)childRow2["NAME"], Convert.ToString(childRow2["PARENT_ID"]));
                                masterNode1.ChildNodes.Add(childNode2);
                                childNode2.Value = Convert.ToString(childRow2["PARENT_ID"]);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
```

But it is not working proper. I dont know where i gone wrong..kindly guide me..

Comment: What exactly isn't working?  Is all the related code present?  Did any exceptions / compiler errors occur?  If so, what are they?

Comment: i dint get the tree structure..I am getting the ROOT NAME and its NAMES. If i click the ROOT NAME it got expanded and its TWO Names are there. I dint get the SUB NAMES...